# Rounding a result from an equation

Tags: python

I seem to have a problem with my code for a simple calculator with equations already codded into it that rounds to decimal points. The problem i have is that I have a variable that has a number from an equation but it isn't rounding to the nearest 2 decimal points when it needs to. Here is an example code:

```
def main():
    variable1 = input("Input number")
    variable2 = input("Input number")
    V1 = float(variable1)
    V2 = float(variable2)
    variablesq = V1*V1
    equation = 20242*(V2/variablesq)
    answer = equation
    round(answer, 2) #This is where the problem is occurring
    print Answer
```

I do believe my mistake is that I'm using a variable instead of a set number but say the answer is 15.2353 it won't round the number from the variable to 15.24

Answer (score 1):

Just calling the function won't do anything. You need to assign the result to something.

```
answer = round(answer, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `"{0:.2f}".format(answer)` that way you don't need to assign it to a variable.